# How can I get the length of an array of objects which is within an array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have attempted googling this question and have searched through stackoverflow but with no success so as a last resort I'm asking just in case anyone can point me in the right direction.

I have put an example of what my code would look like below.

```
var objectInfo = [
{
    name:"object1",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }],
}, {
    name:"object2",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }, {
        name: "bricks",
        quantity:100
    }],
}]
```

My question is, how would I get the length of my materials object array?

My attempt to achieve this was as follows:

```
function getMaterialsArrayLength(objName) {
    for (i = 0; i < objectInfo.length; i++) {
        if (objectInfo[i].name == objName) {
            return objectInfo[i].materials.length
        }
    }    
};
```

However the error returned is "cannot read property materials of undefined". Does anyone have any potential solutions to finding the array length?

I apologise if this has been posted before.

Comment: Missing parenthesis here: `for (i = 0; i < objectInfo.length; i++`<< right here add a `)`. Then it works fine if you call it like `getMaterialsArrayLength('object1')`.

Comment: @wostex fixed that and it did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Why? Your code works now: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/048pqzud/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var objectInfo = [{
  name: "object1",
  materials: [{
    name: "wood",
    quantity: 10
  }, {
    name: "stone",
    quantity: 16
  }],
}, {
  name: "object2",
  materials: [{
    name: "wood",
    quantity: 10
  }, {
    name: "stone",
    quantity: 16
  }, {
    name: "bricks",
    quantity: 100
  }],
}]

function getMaterialsLength(objName) {
  return objectInfo.find(o => o.name === objName).materials.length;
}

console.log(getMaterialsLength('object2'));
```

Might want to add some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the length of an array that does not exist; more precisely, the element of the array you looking at is undefined, so has no material to find the length of:

Answer (score 0):

Just access the object by its index:

```js
var objectInfo = [
{
    name:"object1",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }],
}, {
    name:"object2",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }, {
        name: "bricks",
        quantity:100
    }],
}];

console.log("objectInfo[0].materials.length: " + objectInfo[0].materials.length);
console.log("objectInfo[1].materials.length: " + objectInfo[1].materials.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash.js.

```js
var objectInfo = [
{
    name:"object1",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }],
}, {
    name:"object2",
    materials: [{
        name: "wood",
        quantity:10
    }, {
        name: "stone",
        quantity:16
    }, {
        name: "bricks",
        quantity:100
    }],
}];
function getMaterialsLength(objName) {
  _.each(objectInfo, function(obj) {
      if (obj.name == objName) {  
        console.log(_.size(obj.materials));
      }
  });
}
getMaterialsLength('object2');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.2.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```